# In Typescript, is there a way of checking if an object or function was imported in a "import * as myImport" statement?

Tags: typescript

I'm currently importing all exports from a file as such:

```
import * as strings from "../src/string";
```

I then assign a function to a const depending on a conditional:

```
const decode = (strings._decode) ? strings._decode : strings.decode;
```

Notice that `strings._decode` is not the same as `strings.decode`.

This throws the following error: `Property '_decode' does not exist on type 'typeof import...`.

I'm using `// @ts-ignore` ignore to get around this error, but I was wondering if there was a safe way of doing this.

I'm generating code dynamically, and `_decode` may or may not exist.

Comment: Perhaps you can deterministically export `_decode`. In that case that it shouldn't hold a usable value, explicitly set it to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [declaration reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html) to tell TypeScript that some identifier exists.

So inside your 'string' file you can declare that you are exporting the `_decode()` function (or variable, or whatever type is needed):

```
// src/string.ts
export declare function _decode(): string;
```

and TypeScript will allow you to access that exported member from the module.

```
// you can split the declaration and export
declare function _decode(): string;

// or declare const/let variables
declare const _decode: () => string;

export {
    _decode,
}
```